# How to make PHP form for uploading images with progress bar and showing pictures when they're uploaded?

Tags: php, image, upload, progress

I made uploading script for PHP but the problem is that I would need to make progress bar which shows how much of the picture is uploaded and also when uploading is done I would need to show thumbnail of picture right to uploading form not to confuse users. When it's all done and if user is satisfied with input he's making (because there is description of photo as well) then he clicks on "Save" to end process. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Progress bar can only be done in php 5.4 or with APC. That is the only way upload progress can be reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These might help get you started:

[HTML PHP Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802734/html-php-progress-bar)

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

Once you figure out how to implement the progress bar, you can have some logic which will check if that task completes, echo out `<img src="path of newly uploaded image" />`

Answer (score 1):

Well i think you need to start by dividing your goal in different steps, i suggest by starting with SWFuploader, i use it alot in my projects. I show an progressbar while uploadig.  For the next steps you need to have knowledge about javascript to finish the uploading process.