# how to implement progress bar in php while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I save the image quality to the individual image to the database, then i want to show the image with progress bar value together. I wrote the script but i takes the first image progress bar value.

First half I take the progress bar value from database..

Second half I fetch image together with progress bar value

```html
<?php
$targetid = $_REQUEST['id'];
$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$conn->autocommit(FALSE);   
$query = " SELECT * FROM others " ;
$result1 = $conn->query($query);

if($result1->num_rows >0) {
  while($rowquerycat = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $imgqulty = $rowquerycat['imagefeature'];
    //echo $imgqulty;
?> 
<!---progress-->
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
      value: '<?php echo $imgqulty; ?>'
    });
  });
</script>
<!---end--->
<?php
  }
}
$query = " SELECT * FROM " . TB_OTHERS ;
$result1 = $conn->query($query);

if($result1->num_rows >0) {
  while($rowquerycat = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
?>  
  <div id="progressbar" style="height: 0.5em;width: 50%;margin-left: 30%;" >sample</div>
<?php
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please, format your code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML PHP Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802734/html-php-progress-bar)

Comment: Please remove php close tag above this line 
$query = " SELECT * FROM " . TB_OTHERS ;